# Clarify doubt on article usage

Tags: grammar, articles, indefinite-articles

'A high-quality dentistry' or 'high-quality dentistry'. Kindly clarify as soon as possible.

Comment: Without context we cannot answer your question.  Both statements are grammatically correct in their own usage.  Please provide an example sentence demonstrating how you intend to use the phrase.

Comment: 'A High-Quality Family Dentistry At An Affordable Price.' This is my ad copy, but some are suggesting to remove 'A'. KIndly help.

Comment: @PriyankPandey, in your example, the article "a" is needed, because in this case "dentistry" refers to a dental practice. But if "dentistry" is used to mean something like "high-quality dental work in general", it doesn't need any article because it's an abstract concept, like "literature" or "engineering".

Comment: Compare the difference between 'a grocery' (the establishment) and 'grocery' (what it provides).

Comment: This is a location where dentists do their thing?  In the US, we do not call it "a dentistry" but perhaps "a dental practice" or "a dental office".  Is this from some other country?  Perhaps there they do say "a dentistry".

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments guys, It really helped me to keep my point. I will go with 'A' and let's see whether it's accepted or not.

Comment: @GEdgar 'establishment' in the 'organisation' sense, not the 'place of treatment / selling'.

Answer (score 1):

Ad copy often bends and breaks the rules of grammar due to its overriding necessity of conveying as much meaning as possible in as few words as possible.  If I were using the phrase as a title or header to an advertisement, I would drop the "A" as space-consuming distraction that doesn't add to the meaning.

> **High-Quality Family Dentistry at an Affordable Price!**
>
> Visit us today and meet our family-friendly staff who are ready to help you...

However, if ever brought into the narrative of your ad, the "A" is required for the reasons given in the comments.

> We are a high-quality family dentristry with an affordable price!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Based on this I will put my point of view. Really helpful.

Comment: But the meaning could equally well be 'We offer high-quality dentistry with an affordable price!'

Comment: In the context of ad copy that's an irrelevant distinction.